# Deleting a Key and its occurrence in other key's Value in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary

```
myDict={0: set([1]),1: set([0, 2]),2: set([1, 3]),3: set([2])}
```

and I want to delete 1 from the dictionary ,that means the key "1" and every occurence of 1 in sets of value of other Key .For e.g deleting 1 would make the Dictionary look like

```
myDict={0: set([]),2: set([ 3]),3: set([2])}
```

I am trying to achieve this but not able to do so .Thanks in advance

Comment: "I am trying to achieve this but not able to do so". What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I was not able to achieve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
del myDict[item]
for key, value in myDict.items():
    if item in value:
        myDict[key] = value.difference(set([item]))
```

You can use something like this. First remove the `item` from dictionary, then remove all occurances of it from values using set difference.

Answer (score 2):

A simple not optimized one-liner to remove `value`:

```
{k : v - {value} for k, v in myDict.items() if k != value}
```

Edit: thanks to @mata for the notation `{value}`, I always forget it!

Answer (score 1):

```
val = 1
if val in myDict:
    del myDict[val]
for key in myDict.keys():
   if  isinstance( myDict[key], set) and val in myDict[key]:
        myDict[key].remove(val)
```